# dplyr return only grouping and computed columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this:

```
iris %.% group_by(Species) %.% 
  mutate(v1=Sepal.Length / mean(Sepal.Length)) %.% 
  filter(v1 > 1.15) %.% select(Species:v1)
```

While skipping the `select` bit.  I thought the following should work (but doesn't, for many reasons):

```
iris %.% group_by(Species) %.% 
  select(Species, v1=Sepal.Length / mean(Sepal.Length)) %.% 
  filter(v1 > 1.15)
```

Note in this example I replaced `mutate` with `select` in the hopes that alone would do it.  This also doesn't work because `summarize` expects expressions to return 1 value:

```
iris %.% 
  group_by(Species) %.% 
  summarise(Sepal.Length / mean(Sepal.Length)) %.% 
  filter(v1 > 1.15)
```

Clearly, not a huge deal, but wondering if there is a simpler way of replicating default `data.table` behavior:

```
data.table(iris)[, Sepal.Length / mean(Sepal.Length), by=Species][V1 > 1.15]
```

Which produces just the `by` columns and the computed value:

```
      Species       V1
1:     setosa 1.158610
2: versicolor 1.179245
3: versicolor 1.162399
4:  virginica 1.153613
5:  virginica 1.168792
6:  virginica 1.168792
7:  virginica 1.168792
8:  virginica 1.199150
9:  virginica 1.168792
```

Comment: @Arun, that's right, although I really think `select` should do it.  I can't see the drawback of doing it (though I haven't thought about it too much).  The other solution would be to allow `summarise` to handle multiple rows in the return values of the expressions.

Comment: @Arun, fair point, but I don't want to impose my view of what `select` should do onto `dplyr`; if there is another way of doing this I'd be happy with that too.

Comment: There's no good way currently. See https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/302 for a little discussion.  I don't think `select()` could work like this because of it's current non-standard evaluation rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can now be simplified with dplyr's new `transmute` function which drops any columns except for the grouping variable and cumputed variables (V1 in this case).

```
require(dplyr) # >= 0.3.0.2
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  transmute(v1 = Sepal.Length / mean(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  filter(v1 > 1.15)

#Source: local data frame [9 x 2]
#Groups: Species
#
#     Species       v1
#1     setosa 1.158610
#2 versicolor 1.179245
#3 versicolor 1.162399
#4  virginica 1.153613
#5  virginica 1.168792
#6  virginica 1.168792
#7  virginica 1.168792
#8  virginica 1.199150
#9  virginica 1.168792
```